# Add collapse and expand + mark to HTML tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tree

Add collapse and expand + mark to HTML tree,

CSS3

```
.css-treeview input + label + ul
{
 margin: 0 0 0 22px;
}

.css-treeview input ~ ul
{
display: none;
}

.css-treeview label,
.css-treeview label::before
{
cursor: pointer;
}

.css-treeview input:disabled + label
{
cursor: default;
opacity: .6;
 }

 .css-treeview input:checked:not(:disabled) ~ ul
 {
  display: block;
 }

.css-treeview label,
.css-treeview a,
.css-treeview label::before
 {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 16px;
line-height: 16px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.css-treeview label::before
{
 content: "";
 width: 10px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 background-position: 0 -32px;
}

.css-treeview input:checked + label::before
 {
  background-position: 0 -16px;
 }

/* webkit adjacent element selector bugfix */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{
.css-treeview 
{
    -webkit-animation: webkit-adjacent-element-selector-bugfix infinite 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes webkit-adjacent-element-selector-bugfix 
{
    from 
    { 
        padding: 0;
    } 
    to 
    { 
        padding: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="css-treeview">
<ul class="link1">     
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="item-1" checked="checked" /><label for="item-1">Category 1</label>
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="item-1-0" /><label for="item-1-0">Category 2</label>
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="item-2-2-2"  /><a href="./">Category3.1</a></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="item-2-2-2" /><a href="./">Category 3.2</a></li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="item-2-2-2" /><a href="./">Category 3.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="item-2-2-2" /><a href="./">Category 2.1</a></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="item-2-2-2" /><a href="./">Category 2.2</a></li>
```

In this tree has expand and collapse Category 1 And Category 2. When i click check box, it expand and collapse.I want to add there to + and - marks.
Because + and - mark can show whether tree can expand or not. 
so how can i do it?

Category 2.1 to 2.4 and 3.1 to 3.3 check box should appear.
I only need to change the category 1 and category 2 check box with some + and - mark.

**[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ym95ttxx/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the list-style-image with the image of +/- sign, then use jQuery to check if the list has any children and change the img src accordingly

Comment: Can you help me to do it from jsfiddle. I confused with it :(

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use plugin treeview.js, the look and feel also better this
[Bootstrap treeview](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview)

(or)

If you want to do with custom image and Pure css3 then go this link

[Easy CSS3 Checkboxes and Radio Buttons](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953)